# Calculate the volume of the parallelepiped

Tags: linear-algebra

I've got three vectors, **u**, **v** and **w**. The vectors have length of 1, 2 respectively 3, and the angles between the vectors **u,v** are $\pi/4$, **u,w** are $\pi/3$ and **v,w** are $\pi/6$. I've to calculate the volume of the parallelepiped spanned by these vectors.

If we denote the matrix A with column vectors **u, v** and **w**, we can calculate $AA^T$ to get the following:

$AA^T = |u|^2 + |v|^2 + |w|^2 + 2(u\cdot v + v\cdot w + u\cdot w)$

The determinant can then be calculated as:

$ det A = \sqrt{|u|^2 + |v|^2 + |w|^2 + 2(u\cdot v + v\cdot w + u\cdot w})$

I want to check if my calculations are right. I might be wrong, because when I then crunch the numbers in, I don't get the result I want.

Thank you.

Comment: $AA^T$ is going to be a $3\times 3$ matrix, not a scalar.

Comment: Oh okay, I needed to calculate $A^TA$ instead. But is the last formula correct then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The formula is not correct. The correct way of doing it would be
$$
V^2 = (\det(A))^2 = \det(A^T)\det(A) =\det(A^TA) =\begin{vmatrix}
u\cdot u & u\cdot v & u \cdot w \\
v\cdot u & v\cdot v & v \cdot w \\
w\cdot u & w\cdot v & w \cdot w
\end{vmatrix} \\
= (u\cdot u)(v\cdot v)(w\cdot w) + 2(u\cdot v)(u\cdot w)(v\cdot w) \\
- (u\cdot u)(v\cdot w)^2 - (v\cdot v)(u\cdot w)^2 - (w\cdot w)(u\cdot v)^2 \\
=\|u\|^2\|v\|^2\|w\|^2 \left(1 + 2\cos\alpha\cos\beta\cos\gamma 
-\cos^2\alpha -\cos^2\beta -\cos^2\gamma \right)
$$
Taking the square root on both sides:
$$
V= \|u\|\;\|v\|\;\|w\|\;\sqrt{1 + 2\cos\alpha\cos\beta\cos\gamma 
-\cos^2\alpha -\cos^2\beta -\cos^2\gamma}
$$
Note that you can easily find out that your formula is not correct: When you simultaneously change the length of all three vectors by a factor of $a,$ the the volume of the parallelepiped must change by a factor of $a^3$. This does not happen in your formula. In your formula, it would only change by a factor of $a.$

Comment: Wow, I really liked that answer. Thank you! I think I've a better understanding now. The problem is I thought that multiplying the transpose with the matrix would give me a scalar, as someone in the comments mentioned above.

Answer (score 4):

HINT:

The scalar triple product of three vectors **u**, **v**, and **w**
|**u**$\times$ **v**$\cdot$ **w**| expresses the volume  *V* of parallelepiped also, being equal to:
$$
\begin{vmatrix}
u_1 & v_1 & w_1 \\
u_2 & v_2 & w_2 \\
u_3 & v_3 & w_3 \\
\end{vmatrix} \\
$$